# jQRangeSlider change Range value dynamic using HTML select

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using [jQRangeSlider](http://ghusse.github.io/jQRangeSlider/options.html#optionsUsage)
I want to change Dynamic range of slider. When i will select a Range value automatically initialize and set a selected Range value.

I am using this code.But no range changed seems. I have tried.

**jQuery Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#sliderShow").rangeSlider({
                bounds: {min: 0, max: 100},
                defaultValues:{min: 55, max: 95},
                range: {min: 5, max: false}
    });

    $("#margin").on("change", function(e, data){
                    var rangeChanged  = $(this).val();  
                    $("#sliderShow").rangeSlider({
                        bounds: {min: 0, max: 100},
                        defaultValues:{min: 55, max: 95},
                        range: {min: rangeChanged, max: false}
                    });
    });
});
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<div id="sliderShow"></div>                     
<div id="sliderSetOption">
    Range :
    <select id='margin'>
        <option value="5">5</option>
        <option value="10">10</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
        <option value="20">20</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is in creating the range slider which you already have done versus changing values after it is created.  Look at the documentation you referenced:

```
 // Change options after slider creation
 $("#slider").rangeSlider("option", "bounds", {min: 10, max: 90});
```

So your code would look like this for the deadband change event:

```
 $("#deadband").on("change", function(e, data){
                            var rangeChanged  = $(this).val();  
                            $("#sliderShow").rangeSlider(
                                    "option",
                                    "range",
                                    {min: rangeChanged, max: false}
                            );
  });
```